# Hudson: changing default Tag URL

Tags: svn, hudson, tagging

I'm currently configuring hudson in our company environment and I found out about one small issue. We are using SVN and I'd really like to change default Tag URL in Tag This Build page. We use ANT for building, where I specified target to load version information from a file where it is stored.

Is there a way to pass this variabe from ANT to hudson and use it for Tag URL? We'd really like to not have to write the version number manually each tag.

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to change that in-built functionality

Now, you have 2 possible options i can think of.

- Use Subversion Tagging plugin
  https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Tagging+Plugin
  This will be triggered every time on successful builds.
- If you want to manually tag only selective builds, try using Promotions
  http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Promoted+Builds+Plugin
  Configure a manual promotion process, and run a custom script there to tag SVN
  This is actually what i personally use in my setup